# Colouring areas of a map using just four colors

Tags: r, colors, maps

Is there anyway I can use just four colours (as in Four colour theorem) to automagically fill non-adjacent areas (more than 4 in number) in a map. When I define

`> colors <- brewer.pal(4, "Set1")`

and use it in the plot

`> ggplot() +  geom_sf(data = india_state_dist, aes(fill = factor(State_Name))) + scale_fill_manual(values = colors)`

I get an expected error saying that

`Error in palette(): ! Insufficient values in manual scale. 36 needed but only 4 provided.`

So my question is this: Is there anyway in which 4 colours (or colours lesser than actual count) can be automatically assigned to non-adjacent areas in the map?

Comment: First: use a debugger or  `traceback` to see where  `palette` is called so you can see what argument is wrong.  Second, you should make it clear that `bewer.pal` is from the `RColorBrewer` library.   And, finally, to my knowledge there is no simple algo to assign colors automatically.   Try this paper:    http://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/PAP/fcstoc.pdf

Comment: You've given it a fill variable that has 36 values. Try giving it a factor variable with only 4 values.

Comment: You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76086229/2530121) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28787064/2530121). I could not test the `MapColoring` as I could not install it. The `spdep` solution returned 5 colours, West Bengal was the only state assigned the "5" value. Good luck!

Comment: @LTyrone found the link that will work for you. Use `india_state_dist$Z <- colors[MapColoring::getColoring(as(india_state_dist, "Spatial"))]; ggplot(india_state_dist) + coord_sf() + geom_sf(aes(fill = I(Z)))` (after installing that package). This code worked for me using the `nc` (from my previous comment). (The code for this is nearly identical to the linked dupe, though that answer was using `leaflet`, not much of a difference.)